# Solve the d key given the n and e key for RSA

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I have been given the task by my teacher, to try to find the d key for RSA, if the n and e keys have been given to you. How would you do this? My assumption would be that first you need to find phi(n), then, using the formula d = (kt+1)/e, find k and d? How exactly can you solve for phi(n), and also k and d?

Comment: How many bits is `n`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I would assume n would be a small number, considering the fact that it would take forever to actually find d if it was big. I believe in my teacher's example he used n as 5129 and e as 1483

Comment: Just try all d, 1<d<n.

Comment: that is easy with the Linux `factor` command to find the factors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got a serious task there? Because there is no feasible known way for getting d efficiently for given n and e using non quantum computers.

Comment: Yes, these were his exact words:"unfortunately, the user “
forgot” what value he chose for d, but does know the values of n and e. The program must be modular, commented and efficient. "

Comment: Then your problem is supposed to be hard. There is a polynomial time algorithm giving you p and q for n=pq if d is given. This means that your problem is equivalent to the factorization problem. I think that there are more approaches to this problem, but many are very complex to gain at least a bit of efficiency. So you could have a look into those approaches.